# SQL: Query where variable is suffix of field and viceversa

Tags: sql, expression, suffix

Suppose I have an arbitrary string (for example 'AABCC')  and I want to get every row where [col] is equal to this string with any prefix. In that case I would do:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE [col] LIKE '%AABCC';
```

In my example I would get matches such as 'EEEAABCC', etc.

Now I want to do the inverse thing. I want to get matches where my string is equal to [col] with any prefix:

For example, I would like to get rows where [col] is 'BCC', 'ABCC', etc.

How would I do this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to match? Your two examples are *substrings* of your target string, and the full list of matches like that would be 'C', 'CC', 'BCC', 'ABCC', and 'AABCC', but I don't think this is what you're really after. Can you help us out?

Comment: If you mean "[col] is my string plus any suffix", it would be `where [col] like 'AABCC%'`, but it seems you're looking for something else?

Comment: Ok, I should have said my string plus any prefix. I will edit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want any column that matches the rightmost part of your string for its entire length:

```
SELECT col FROM tbl
WHERE col LIKE RIGHT('rrrabcd', LENGTH(col))
```

(Performance for this query is going to be pretty bad since it will have to compute the expression for every row. You may want to rethink your problem if you are doing this often on a lot of data.)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM NAMES WHERE 
  SUBSTR('AABBCC', LENGTH('AABBCC') - LENGTH(Name) + 1, LENGTH(Name)) = Name;
```

Notes:

- Substitute `SUBSTR` with `SUBSTRING`, or `MID`, or whatever your RDBMS supports.
- Substitute `LENGTH` with `LEN`, or `STRLEN`, or whatever your RDBMS supports.

Comment: Thank you. What is the difference with respect to Andrew's answer? They look pretty much the same

Comment: Yes, the two answers are very similar. Andrew's answer is better. (Provided that your RDBMS has a `RIGHT()` function. They usually do.  But if not, then you can emulate it using `SUBSTR()` and `LENGTH()` as my answer shows.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match on the last N characters of [col] being equal to the last N characters of your target string, something like this would do:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE [col] like '%AABCC' --match on entire target string
OR [col] like '%ABCC'     --match on last 4 chars of target string
OR [col] like '%BCC'      --match on last 3 chars of target string
OR [col] like '%CC'       --match on last 2 chars of target string
OR [col] like '%C'        --match on last 1 char of target string
;
```

Is this really what you want to match on?

Comment: Well, yes, but the string 'AABCC'  was just an example, it could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE 'CCBAA' like concat(reverse([col]), '%')